# How to extend a complex Android view like the GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, custom-controls, android-custom-view

### Background:

I'm looking for a way to extend the `GridView` I need implement a col- and row-span like in HTML. I have hunderds of elements so I cannot use e.g. a `TableLayout`. However that would be *too localized*. So far I reduce the question to **how to extend the GridView?**

### What I have tried and where I have failed:

My first approach was to look which methods I need to replace and I found some private methods which cannot be overriden. So I tried to copy the hole source code from the `GridView` to a new class called *CustomGrid*. That was a terrible failure since I cannot access the `com.android.internal.R` class.

Then I dropped that idea and looked if I can normal extend the class and replace all the private methods with custom copies. I took a pen and build a huge tree where all methods are used.

After I found all references I tried to extend the class *normal* and I added the first method:

```
private View fillDown(int pos, int nextTop) {
    View selectedView = null;

    int end = (mBottom - mTop);
    if((mGroupFlags & CLIP_TO_PADDING_MASK) == CLIP_TO_PADDING_MASK) {
        end -= mListPadding.bottom;
    }

    // ...
```

Here is my next problem that member variables `mBottom` and `mTop` are unknown. I digged a little through the sources and found them finally in the `View` class, but unfortunately they are hidden.

```
/**
 * The distance in pixels from the top edge of this view's parent
 * to the bottom edge of this view.
 * {@hide}
 */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "layout")
protected int mBottom;
```

### Question:

How can I extend the `GridView` without hitting that lamentations and without the usage of massive reflection? I mean it seems to be impossible to write that as a pure custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I extend the GridView without hiting that limentations and without the usage of massive reflection?

Most likely, you don't. You copy the code into your project and modify to suit, including all requisite superclasses (up to `ViewGroup`). I will be stunned if you can achieve your aims by a simple subclass of `GridView`. You may even have to completely write your desired widget from scratch.

> That was a terrible failior due I cannot access the com.android.internal.R class.

You will also need to copy over relevant resources, then fix up `R` references to point to your own resources.

> but unforcantly they are hidden.

You find other ways of getting this data. `mBottom`, for example, can be changed to `getBottom()`.

Comment: I'm really happy to get an answer from you, but unfortunately this is not the answer I would like to read. That means that I will need to rewrite about 4k lines of code to achieve my goal?

Comment: @rekire: Depending upon your UI objectives, you could look at `StaggeredGridView`, either to just use (ideal) or as code base to start from instead of `GridView` itself. http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

Comment: I think I found that view too. If I remember correctly it used two `ListView`s to achive that effect, that would fix my problem with the colspan, but not the rowspan.

Comment: @rekire: Then you either need to revisit your UI and change it to fit what Android can do natively (or via existing third-party components such as `StaggeredGridView`), or be prepared to write a ton of code. Writing an `AdapterView` is not easy. You also might consider running an experiment with using `GridLayout` in a `ScrollView` to see exactly how your code performs (CPU, heap space).

Comment: You are right. That homepage is anyway extremly helpful. Thank you for sharing it!

Comment: I just found on that site the [quiltview](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/quiltview-library/). I will use that :-)